# Iterate through nested Javascript Objects from API response

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've tried 100 different things, and spend days looking through Google and Stackoverflow, but I can't find a solution to this problem. Everything I call after the body of this API response returns *undefined*!

The response from Facebook SDK looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "body": "[   
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "Larry Syid Wright",
                    "administrator": false,
                    "id": "xxx"
                },      {         
                    "name": "Melissa Long Jackson",
                    "administrator": false,
                    "id": "xxx"
                },      {       
                    "name": "Charlotte Masson",
                    "administrator": false,
                    "id": "xxx"  
                }  
            ],   
            "paging": {      
                "next": "url"
            }
        ]"
    },{
        "body": "{   
            "data": [      
                {         
                    "id": "xxx_xxx",       
                    "message": "In honor of Halloween, how many of you have your own ghost stories?  Who believes in ghosts and who doesn't?",                 
                    "type": "status",         
                    "created_time": "2014-10-31T20:02:01+0000",         
                    "updated_time": "2014-11-01T02:52:51+0000",         
                    "likes": {            
                        "data": [               
                            {                  
                                "id": "xxx",                  
                                "name": "Joe HerBatman Owenby Jr." 
                            }          
                        ],            
                    }
                    "paging": {               
                        "cursors": 
                            {                  
                                "after": "xxx",                  
                                "before": "xxx"               
                            }            
                        }         
                    }
                },{         
                    "id": "xxx_xxx",         
                    "from": {            
                        "id": "xxx",            
                        "name": "Jessica Starling"         
                    },       
                    "message": "Watching the "Campaign" and I can't help but notice what a fantastic job they did (Will ferrell and all) with that North Carolina accent! Ya'll know we sound different than other southern states ;)",         
                    "type": "status",           
                    "created_time": "2014-11-01T02:36:21+0000",         
                    "updated_time": "2014-11-01T02:36:21+0000",         
                    "likes": {            
                        "data": [               
                            {                  
                                "id": "xxx",                  
                                "name": "Scott Williams"n               
                            }         
                        ]
                    }      
                }      
            ],   
            "paging": {      
                "previous": "xxx",      
                "next": "xxx"  
            }
        }"
    }
]
```

This response is from a batch call. If I call them separately, I can easily iterate through the responses, and get everything from them. When I call them in the batch though, I can't get past "body", and I need to use a batch call.

`console.log(response[0].body);` will return the object inside the **body** of the first part of the response, but `console.log(response[0].body.data);` returns *undefined*. I just don't get it. This should be simple but it's like there's a lock on the door and I don't have the right key.

I normally have no issue iterating through objects, so I don't need a generalized answer. I need help seeing whatever it is here that I don't see. Why does the console show *undefined* when I call anything after the **body**, and what do I need to be doing to get any of these values?

Comment: These `body` values are just giant strings - essentially embedded JSON.  You'd have to separate parse them as JSON to get at their internal values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That JSON contains nested JSON. body seems to be a string. Use

```
var body = JSON.parse(response[0].body);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even know a response would be a string. What's the point of that?

Comment: Check out the following article, it will totally answer your question: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @istos that definitely explains things, and makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Strings kind of makes sense, considering responses are strings, you have an array of responses (think of ajax responses having a responseText property) and their bodies are strings. Was this a call that combined multiple endpoints? @istos I am not sure how that article applies here, nobody was calling the object JSON

Comment: @Juan Mendes, The OP found it helpful and the article totally relates, you just have to read the whole article and not just the title.

Comment: @istos I have read the article, it's explaining that JSON is a string and objects are the result of parsing those strings. I am still trying to find the connection between the problem the OP mentioned and the article. Maybe you're saying that there is JSON inside JSON...

Comment: @JuanMendes, what I'm saying is that the OP was obviously confused about the difference of JSON Strings vs JavaScript Object literals because he asked why the API returned a string and obviously he didn't know about JSON.parse. If he had known the difference, he would have not asked why he got a string in the response. That article explains the difference and a lot more. Does that make sense?

Comment: @istos I kind of see what you're saying, I guess I thought the OP just didn't see the quotes around the array.

Answer (score 1):

The values from the body are just strings.which are embedded as json.So firstly you would need to parse them using `JSON.parse`.

The code would be like

```
var body = JSON.parse(response[0].body);
```

Comment: Thanks! Someone answered ahead of you with the same thing, so I marked that one as the answer. I got what I needed though so thank you!

Comment: it fine ...:) ..Hapy coding